# Symfony custom authentication provider failure messages

Tags: symfony, authentication

I have create custom form authentication provider and I need to create messages when authentication fails. It's fine when I throw `BadCredentialsException()` as it gets redirected to login page with the error message "Bad credentials" but what if I need different messages for different failures? For example I need errors then the account is blocked or IP is banned. How can I achieve that? Currently I through Exceptions which leads to 500 internal error.

I got written custom authentication listener which extends `AbstractAuthenticationListener` and authentication provider which implements `AuthenticationProviderInterface`

Errors where the form is rendered are passed from the controller using `$authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to create another exception which would extend the `BadCredentialsException` and override the function which returns the message